# Angular email validation with double dots

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

I have a problem with e-mail validation. I use a Angular.js. 
In my form I have a input:

```
<input class="form-control input-flat-underline"
                               ng-pattern="/^[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]+$/"
                               id="email" name="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" required type="email">
```

The e-mail

> test@test..com

is not ok but validation passed, But e-mail is not correct. I think the problem is in ng-pattern.

Comment: Becaus `test@test..com` is not valid email address.

Comment: yes, but validation passed

Comment: You don't need ng-pattern when you have type="email", it contains the email validation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to validate email address. So in this case you don't need to create your own regular expression pattern, because the proper one is going to be [quite complex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). You don't want to do this.

And this is the reason, why you had this problem: even though "test@test..com" passess ngPattern validation (but it should *not*, this is *not valid* email address, and your regular expression is [not standard compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)), it fails on type="email" validation (Angular one).

Angular has build-in email validation regular expression (this one [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4ae4cc9d469f0327c6576d8bd8ac7f402ddffa2d/src/ng/directive/input.js#L27)) which you can make use of simply by using input `type="email"`. So in your case to make correct email address validation all you need to do is to remove ngPattern:

```
<input class="form-control input-flat-underline" id="email" name="email" 
        ng-model="ctrl.user.email" 
        required 
        type="email">
```

Comment: Use `ng-message="email"` instead of `ng-message="pattern"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the angular built-in email validation by removing the ng-pattern option from the input tag. 
Like the following:

```
<input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text"  required>
```

Otherwise you can try the validation with the following:

```
<input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" required>
```